# Create a list of strings with one/multiple character replacement

Tags: python-3.x

How to create a whole list of string from one string where each string in the list containing exactly one character replacement? The string itself is consisted of only four characters (say: A, B, C, and D), so that the whole list of a string of length n would contain 3n+1 strings with exactly one character replacement.

Example:
inputstr = 'ABCD'
output = ['ABCD', 'BBCD', 'CBCD', 'DBCD', 'AACD', 'ACCD', 'ADCD', 'ABAD', 'ABBD', 'ABDD', 'ABCA', 'ABCB', 'ABCC']

I write the following python code:

```
strin = 'ABCD'
strout = set()

tempstr1 = ''
tempstr2 = ''
tempstr3 = ''
tempstr4 = ''
for base in range(len(strin)):
    if strin[base] == 'A':  #this block will be repeated for char B, C and D
        tempstr1 = strin.replace(strin[base], 'A')
        strout.add(tempstr1)
        tempstr1 = ''

        tempstr2 = strin.replace(strin[base], 'B')
        strout.add(tempstr2)
        tempstr2 = ''

        tempstr3 = strin.replace(strin[base], 'C')
        strout.add(tempseq3)
        tempstr3 = ''

        tempstr4 = strin.replace(strin[base], 'D')
        strout.add(tempseq4)
        tempstr4 = ''

return strout
```

and it works well as long as there is no repeated character (such as 'ABCD'). However, when the input string contains repeated character (such as 'AACD'), it will return less than 3n+1 string. I tried with 'AACD' string and it returns only 10 instead of 13 strings.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

change 

`strout = set() ===> strout = list()`

Comment: previously I tried strout = list(), but it resulted a list containing sting duplicates..

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I used a slicing method to create a list of total combination of strings with one replacement.

```
for i in range(len(seq)):
  seqxlist.append(seq[:i] + 'x' + seq[i+1:])
```

and after that I filter out all the x-replaced strings which are longer than the original string length:

```
seqxlist = [x for x in seqxlist if (len(x) == len(seq))]
```

Then, I changed x into any of the substitution characters:

```
for m in seqxlist:     
  tempseq1 = m.replace('x', 'A')
  outseq.append(tempseq1)

  tempseq2 = m.replace('x', 'B')
  outseq.append(tempseq2)

  tempseq3 = m.replace('x', 'C')
  outseq.append(tempseq3)

  tempseq4 = m.replace('x', 'D')
  outseq.append(tempseq4)
```

This will create all the possible combinations of string replacement, but still contains duplicates. To remove duplicates, I use `set()` to the `outseq` list.